# Algorithm to compute k fractions of form 1/r summing up to 1

Tags: algorithm

Given `k`, we need to write `1` as a sum of `k` fractions of the form `1/r`.

For example,

1. For `k=2`, `1` can uniquely be written as `1/2 + 1/2`.
2. For `k=3`, `1` can be written as `1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3` or `1/2 + 1/4 + 1/4` or `1/6 + 1/3 + 1/2`

Now, we need to consider all such set of `k` fractions that sum upto `1` and return the highest denominator among all such sets; for instance, the sample case 2, our algorithm should return `6`.

I came across this problem in a coding competition and couldn't come up with an algorithm for the same. A bit of Google search later revealed that such fractions are called **Egyption Fractions** but probably they are set of distinct fractions summing upto a particular value (not like `1/2 + 1/2`). Also, I couldn't find an algo to compute Egyption Fractions (if they are at all helpful for this problem) when their number is restricted by `k`.

Comment: [Greedy algorithm for Egyptian fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm_for_Egyptian_fractions)

Comment: @JimMischel That's a nice article, but it doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: @JimMischel I did come across this approach but as I mentioned in the question, Egyptian Fractions are **DISTINCT** fractions. Also, the greedy algorithm proposed does not take into consideration that I want exactly `k` such fractions.

Comment: There's a very good article here. http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fractions/egyptian.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If all you want to do is find the largest denominator, there's no reason to find all the possibilities. You can do this very simply:

```
public long largestDenominator(int k){
    long denominator = 1;
    for(int i=1;i<k;i++){
        denominator *= denominator + 1;
    } 
    return denominator;
}
```

For you recursive types:

```
public long largestDenominator(int k){
    if(k == 1)
        return 1;
    long last = largestDenominator(k-1);
    return last * (last + 1); // or (last * last) + last)
}
```

---

### Why is it that simple?

To create the set, you need to insert the largest fraction that will keep it under `1` at each step(except the last). By "largest fraction", I mean by value, meaning the smallest denominator.

For the simple case `k=3`, that means you start with `1/2`. You can't fit another half, so you go with `1/3`. Then `1/6` is left over, giving you three terms.

For the next case `k=4`, you take that `1/6` off the end, since it won't fit *under* one, and we need room for another term. Replace it with `1/7`, since that's the biggest value that fits. The remainder is `1/42`.

Repeat as needed.

---

For example:

- *2* : [2,2]
- *3* : [2,3,6]
- *4* : [2,3,7,42]
- *5* : [2,3,7,43,1806]
- *6* : [2,3,7,43,1807,3263442]

As you can see, it rapidly becomes very large. Rapidly enough that you'll overflow a `long` if `k>7`. If you need to do so, you'll need to find an appropriate container (ie. BigInteger in Java/C#).

It maps perfectly to [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A007018):

> `a(n) = a(n-1)^2 + a(n-1), a(0)=1`.

You can also see the relationship to [Sylvester's sequence](http://oeis.org/A000058):

> `a(n+1) = a(n)^2 - a(n) + 1, a(0) = 2`

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence#Connection_with_Egyptian_fractions) has a very nice article explaining the relationship between the two, as pointed out by Peter in the comments.

Comment: +1: And [Sylvester's sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm_for_Egyptian_fractions#Sylvester.27s_sequence_and_closest_approximation) proves that this answer must be optimal (or you will have found a closer approximation to 1)

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz And it's on Wikipedia! I should do some research next time rather than proving it to myself on pen/paper >.<

Comment: Thanks for such a simple solution. And I was cursing the problem settlers for including an apparently difficult problem in a 1-hour contest. I have a long way to go. Anyway, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of Egyptian fractions before but here are some thoughts:

**Idea**

You can think of them geometrically:

- Start with a unit square (1x1)
- Draw either vertical or horizontal lines dividing the square into equal parts.
- Repeat optionally the drawing of lines inside any of the sub-boxes evenly.
- Stop any time you want.

The rectangles present will form a set of fractions of the form 1/n that add to 1.

You can count them and they might equal your 'k'.

Depending on how many equal sections you divided a rectangle into, it will tell whether you have 1/2 or 1/3 or whatever. 1/6 is 1/2 of 1/3 or 1/3 of 1/2. (i.e. You dived by 2 and then one of the sub-boxes by 3 OR the other way around.)

**Idea 2**

You start with 1 box. This is the fraction 1/1 with k=1.

When you sub-divide by n you add n to the count of boxes (k or of fractions summed) and subtract 1.

When you sub-divide any of those boxes, again, subtract 1 and add n, the number of divisions. Note that n-1 is the number of lines you drew to divide them.

**More**

You are going to start searching for the answer with k. Obviously k * 1/k = 1 so you have one solution right there.

How about k-1?

There's a solution there: (k-2) * 1/(k-1) + 2 * (1/((k-1)*2))

How did I get that? I made k-1 equal sections (with k-2 vertical lines) and then divided the last one in half horizontally.

Each solution is going to consist of:

- taking a prior solution
- using j less lines and some stage and dividing one of the boxes or sub-boxes into j+1 equal sections.

I don't know if all solutions can be formed by repeating this rule starting from k * 1/k

I do know you can get effective duplicates this way. For example: k * 1/k with j = 1 => (k-2) * 1/(k-1) + 2 * (1/((k-1)*2)) [from above] but k * 1/k with j = (k-2) => 2 * (1/((k-1)*2)) + (k-2) * 1/(k-1) [which just reverses the order of the parts]

**Interesting**

k = 7 can be represented by 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... + 1/(2^6) + 1/(2^6) and the general case is 1/2 + ... + 1/(2^(k-1)) + 1/(2^(k-1)).

Similarly for any odd k it can be represented by 1/3 + ... + 3 * [1/(3^((k-1)/2)].

I suspect there are similar patterns for all integers up to k.